# Matplotlib: Is there a way to get/set full figure size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

All methods I know of, including `set_size_inches`, only change the axis size. E.g. this is a figure produced after calling `fig.set_size_inches(5, 5)` and it's obviously not square (the axis is, though):

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2])
plt.xticks([0.2, 0.8], ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'], rotation=90)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 5)
```

Is there a way to set size or aspect ratio of the entire figure? A brute force solution might be calculating widths and heights of the title, xticks and yticks using `get_window_extent`, distances between e.g. title and axis, axis and xlabels etc, and using maths to determine how much the axis itself needs to be changed to account for existing title, labels etc.

The end goal is to produce an image which has a set aspect ratio. Note, the image, not the axis. Although having the axis that honors the aspect ratio of the image would be extra nice.

Comment: `fig.set_size_inches(7, 7)` produces a square figure for me. Can you include a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to produce your error?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I guess it's good that you already try to share your thoughts about a possible solution, but the problem itself is not really clear. What do you not like about the current figure and what do you want to change. Providing a reproducible example will also help to see the problem.

Comment: `fig.set_size_inches(5, 5)` works as expected. The problem seems to be that you are running this in jupyter notebook or Jupyterconsole? That appends the question: Do you want to have a square figure in the output of the jupyter on screen or for the saved output image?

Comment: Im running this in a notebook.  Running `fig.savefig` produces an image which is cropped at the bottom. To get the full image saved, I have to run ```bbox_extra_artists = fig.get_default_bbox_extra_artists();
fig.savefig('path/to/file', bbox_extra_artists=bbox_extra_artists, bbox_inches='tight', frameon=True)``` Preferrably, i'd  like a square image both in the notebook and saved.

Comment: It sounds like this is a problem with the `notebook` backend for matplotlib. You may want to open an issue on Github somewhere. I also can't reproduce the problem with your new example from the command line.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon could i please see the figure that you get with that code?